# How to loop through tuple and add values into dictionary python

Tags: python

I have this tuple that has been fetched from a database:

[image: Tuple]

I would like to iterate through the tuple and add all the numeric values by their key into a dictionary.

My desired output: {'Rent' : -100.0, 'Groceries' : -20.0, 'Rent' : -64.0, 'Other' : -3.3, 'Bills' : -18.0}
(if my math is correct)

As you can see I want to add all the rent values together, groceries values etc. into a dictionary.

I have tried using the regular dict() function, but it only grabs the first value of each type and leaves the rest:

[image: code]

[image: output]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please paste code and output as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) rather than as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: You can not have duplicate keys in a dictionary, that means every key has to be a unique key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the list and if the key exists in dictionary, increment it otherwise add the new key and value to it,

```
lst = [('Rent',-50.0),('Groceries',-20.0),('Rent',-70.0),('Groceries',-18.0)]

dict = {}
for tp in lst:
    if tp[0] not in dict:
        dict[tp[0]] = tp[1]
    else:
        dict[tp[0]] = dict[tp[0]] + tp[1]
    
print(dict)

O/P: {'Rent': -120.0, 'Groceries': -38.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

totals = defaultdict(float)

for name, amount in values:
    totals[name] += amount
```

If you try to access the `defaultdict` with a key that doesn't exist, the factory function (`float`, in this case) will be called. Creating the default value of `0.0`.